# Is there a shortcut overlap operators?

Tags: c++, operators

I have a  `void operator+` and  `operator+=`
How do I overlap them. I know that if I copy the same code in both functions it will work. I am more curious is there a shorter way without needing to copy the entire code?

Comment: Do you really think this is enough details about what you have and why you don't like it?

Comment: call one from another

Comment: @StoryTeller Sorry I don't get what your trying to say. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @King23 - Amusingly enough, this is what I asked of you.

Comment: @StoryTeller 2 operators(+ and +=) do the same thing to object variables. They receive the same parameters and increase the variables in the identical way. How do I decrease code size by pointing one to the other ?     Also I find it amusing how before I was criticized for subjectivity and excess use of details in the description and now the opposite. Guess I went full circle

Comment: Rather than retype your post in a comment, improve you post. Add a bit more code and make sure the issue is clear. And yes, there is a delicate balance to walk. Welcome to SO.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement one and call that from another, I mean you don't really need to duplicate the code, remember that

```
c += 20;
```

is the same as

```
c = c + 20;
```

so your + operator should instead of duplicate the code, wisely call the overloaded += operator

Comment: No. Conventional wisdom advises to call it the other way around, with parameters properly adjusted.

Comment: Hi! @StoryTeller, thanks for the comment.... but I dont spot the benefit...can you please tell me more

Comment: `foo operator+ (foo lhs, foo const& rhs) { lhs += rhs; return lhs; }`. This is short, neat, and since C++17 highly susceptible to copy elision and NRVO.

Comment: wrapping the + operator will involve more copies / moves than the other direction

Comment: Done! thanks a lot to both for the neat comment!!!